# Copy row from one sheet to another when a cell value is negative

Tags: excel, vba, copy

I have code in which if column I, it will look at that value and then send an email if it matches any of my limits. Then I have also included a refresh anytime I edit another column.

This code is in ThisWorkbook

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
    Call Worksheet_Calculated
End Sub
```

This is my code in Sheet1 that will run the operation if anything in column G changes.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Target.Address Like "$F$*" Then
        Call Worksheet_Calculated
    End If
End Sub
```

This code is in a module. It checks to see if any value in column I is any of of the MyLimit Values, if it is, in column I, it will say sent or not sent. If sent, an email will be generated.

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub Worksheet_Calculated()

    Dim FormulaRange As Range
    Dim NotSentMsg As String
    Dim MyMsg As String
    Dim SentMsg As String
    Dim MyLimita As Double
    Dim MyLimitb As Double
    Dim MyLimitc As Double
    Dim MyLimitd As Double

    NotSentMsg = "Not Sent"
    SentMsg = "Sent"

    'Above the MyLimit value it will run the macro
    MyLimita = 100
    MyLimitb = 50
    MyLimitc = 10
    MyLimitd = 1

    'Set the range with Formulas that you want to check
    'This is the column that shows how many days left

    Set FormulaRange = Range("H5:H25")

    On Error GoTo EndMacro:
    For Each FormulaCell In FormulaRange.Cells
        With FormulaCell
            If IsNumeric(.Value) = False Then
                MyMsg = ""
            ElseIf (.Value = MyLimita Or .Value = MyLimitb Or .Value = MyLimitc Or .Value = MyLimitd) Then
                    MyMsg = SentMsg
                    If .Offset(0, 1).Value = NotSentMsg Then
                        Call Mail_with_outlook(FormulaCell)
                    End If
            Else
                MyMsg = NotSentMsg
            End If
            Application.EnableEvents = False
            .Offset(0, 1).Value = MyMsg
            Application.EnableEvents = True
        End With
    Next FormulaCell

ExitMacro:
    Exit Sub

EndMacro:
    Application.EnableEvents = True

    MsgBox "Some Error occurred." _
         & vbLf & Err.Number _
         & vbLf & Err.Description

End Sub
```

The above code will call another module which will populate the email that I would like to send.

```
Option Explicit

Public FormulaCell As Range

Public Sub Mail_with_outlook(FormulaCell As Range)
    Dim OutApp As Object
    Dim OutMail As Object
    Dim strto As String, strcc As String, strbcc As String
    Dim strsub As String, strbody As String

    Set OutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
    Set OutMail = OutApp.CreateItem(0)

'Change the parenthesis for column that the email is in

    strto = Cells(FormulaCell.Row, "K").Value
    strcc = ""
    strbcc = ""
    strsub = "Payment Notification (PO --Enter PO # Here--)"

'Change the parenthesis for the Column that the POC is in

    strbody = "Hi " & Cells(FormulaCell.Row, "J").Value & vbNewLine & vbNewLine & _
              "This is a reminder to pay for a licensing/maintenance bill in: " & Cells(FormulaCell.Row, "H").Value & " days." & _
              vbNewLine & vbNewLine & "Line 2" & _
              vbNewLine & "Line 3" & _
              vbNewLine & "Line 4" & _
              vbNewLine & "Line 5" & _
              vbNewLine & "Line 6"

    With OutMail
        .To = strto
        .CC = strcc
        .BCC = strbcc
        .Subject = strsub
        .Body = strbody
        'You can add a file to the mail like this
        '.Attachments.Add ("C:\test.txt")
        .Display    ' or use .Send
    End With

    Set OutMail = Nothing
    Set OutApp = Nothing
End Sub
```

I want to continue running this code on start up and whenever column G is edited, but only in Sheet1.

I want when column I is negative to copy that entire row into sheet2.

Comment: If you don't specify a sheet in your code, the default is the active sheet. try something like `Worksheets("Sheet1").Range`

Comment: As per comment above, consider changing `Set FormulaRange = Range("I5:I25")` to `Set FormulaRange = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("I5:I25")` where Sheet1 is the name of the actual sheet you are working on.

Comment: Thanks, the Set FormulaRange = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("I5:I25") fixed the problem of only running the macro on the one sheet

Comment: So how do you add in a code that will copy over the corresponding row if the values in Column I are negative and paste them to a new sheet?

When I originally wrote this, I was not intending on adding new sheets to this and I am not sure where to write the codes to do this procedure

Comment: Hi Mariam, [here is how to loop through worksheets in a workbook](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/142126/macro-to-loop-through-all-worksheets-in-a-workbook)